# C# generic function to search for object base on condition and also support future properties

Tags: c#, list, generics

So i have this `class`:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id{ get; set; }
    }
```

And i have this `Collection`:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
```

So so example if i want `Person` with specific `Name`:

```
public Person Search(string property )
{
    return persons.Find(x => x.Name == property);
}
```

So now i am wonder how to write generic `function` that search for specific `Person` object base on some `property` and this `function` will also need to support future `Property` that at this time does not exist but if it will add to my class `Person` it will also works.

Comment: Isn´t the `Find`-method what you want? It already does exactly what you want: searching by a **predicate**. So if you exposed `persons` publicly, you can just call `Find` on it. Otherwise make your `Search`-method expect a `Func<Person, bool>` and pass that parameter to `Find`.

Comment: [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `Find`-method already does this, there´s no need to create your own method for you, unless you don´t want to expose your list to the outside of your class.

In this case make your `Search`-method expect a [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public Person Search(Predicate<Person> predicate)
{
    return persons.Find(predicate);
}
```

Now you may easily use this like this:

```
Person p = myClass.Search(x => x.Name == "Me");
```

or

```
Person p = myClass.Search(x => x.Age > 40);
```

In case you have multiple objects that fit your condition you may either use `List<T>.FindAll(predicate)` or `IEnumerable<T>.Where(predicate)`. For the latter however you´d have to use a `Func<Person, bool>` instead of a `Predicate<Person>`:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Search(Func<Person, bool> predicate)
{
    return persons.Where(predicate);
}
```

which can be used exactly the same way as the above examples (except that it returns a collection of items instead a single one).

Comment: 2 questions: 1. please show me how to use you method example 2. what if i add another property called int Age and i want to search for person that his age bigger then some value ?

Comment: And in case i have several objects that mach my search ?

Comment: @ErofhTor - You defined your method to return a single `Person` and invoked another method designed to do the same. If you want to return multiples then there are existing methods that do that as well, such as [`List<T>.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`Enumerable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__).

Answer (score 0):

```
public T Search<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(filter);
}
```

Usage:

```
var erofh = Search(people, q => q.Name == "Erofh Tor");
```